# pass function multiple integers and iterate over them

Tags: javascript, jquery

The counts I get are fetched from an api, for simplicity i've just hard coded integers to represent my problem.

I need to iterate through vars **fbCount**, **tweetCount**, and **pinCount**, and do something when they're over 1k.

I'm a ruby guy, pretty sure i'm making a silly move. The error I get is:
**uncaught type error  object  18000 has no method 'each'**

```
var fbCount        = 18000,
    tweetCount     = 0,
    pinCount       = 0;

function somethingByCount(count) {
    count.each(function() { 
         alert("firing each count")
    });
  }

somethingByCount(fbCount,tweetCount,pinCOunt);
```

Comment: Well, error seems descriptive, numbers don't have a method `each`...

Comment: This isn't remotely how JS works. What do you expect `count` to be? I can tell you what it _is_ in this case: `18000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to get the list of arguments

Using [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate - cross browser

```
function somethingByCount() {
    $.each(arguments, function(idx, val) { 
        alert("firing each count:" + val)
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/azdpL)

Using native [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate - only on modern browsers

```
function somethingByCount() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(val, idx){
        console.log("firing each count:", val)
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pwwVt/)

Comment: thank you for providing a doc, answering the question, and not being snarky.

Answer (score 1):

The function expects the argument to be an array, so you have to wrap them in brackets:

```
somethingByCount([fbCount, tweetCount, pingCount]);
```

Or you could change the function to use the `arguments` variable, which contains an array of all the parameters:

```
function somethingByCount() {
    arguments.each(function() {
        alert("firing each count");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can use an array

```
    var fbCount        = 18000,
    tweetCount     = 0,
    pinCount       = 0;

    var data=new Array(fbCount,tweetCount,pinCount);

function somethingByCount(count) {
    $(count).each(function() { 
         alert("firing each count")
    });
  }

somethingByCount(data);
```